# Does our home heating boiler need to be inspected/serviced?

Tags: furnace, maintenance

We have hot water heating (that is the boiler heats water and pumps it to different parts of the house) and the unit is about 12 years old. It is a Utica gas boiler. As far as I can tell, it is working fine.

Is it time to bring in a professional for some maintenance? If so, what would he do?

Comment: Brand and model boiler would help us give you advice.

Comment: It is a Utica boiler. I do not know the model. I looked on the unit.

Comment: Without knowing what version you have, here's a Utica Gas Boiler installation and owner's manual for the MGB boilers from their website. https://uticaboilers.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/240012785-UB-MGB-K-IOM-REV-C-WEB.pdf Maintenance starts on Page 29. It calls for annual pre-season servicing.  Try using a flashlight and your cell phone camera to look at inconveniently located data plates to identify your specific boiler, which are almost certainly there, typically near the gas inlet pipe.

Comment: The model number is MGB-100J and the serial number is 2913000604S .

Comment: Based upon this information, can somebody tell me how old my unit is. Could it be that it was made in 1990?

Comment: Appears to be 29th week of 2013. https://www.building-center.org/utica-hvac-age/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is common/normal and in some LAHJs (Local Authority Having Jurisdiction) required (or - by some insurance companies required, though they might not bother to point that out so they can deny a claim because you didn't) to have an annual maintenance check of fuel-burning appliances, to clean and adjust and verify safe operation. The person doing the check may need a license specifically for gas appliance work, depending on LAHJ.

As noted in comments, [Utica boiler](https://uticaboilers.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/240012785-UB-MGB-K-IOM-REV-C-WEB.pdf) suggests an annual pre-season maintenance check.

12 years is quite a bit long for a maintenance interval.

12 years should not normally be anywhere near the lifetime for a quality boiler.

Typical tasks - check and adjust fuel/air ratio. Clean boiler heat exchanger. Verify correct operation of safety systems. Check flue for proper venting. Inspect for any signs of leaks.